# How to extract following string with HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I would like to extract the price from following HTML string:

```
<span class="bold colorwhite size11 floatLeft textCenter cartbox_right">&euro; 150,42</span>
```

The website makes it a bit more easier since this span class exists only once, yet the program doesn't work as it should. It outputs:

```
euro; 0,00
```

Here's how my code looks like:

```
private string getTextfrom()
{

    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = webGet.Load(txtURL.Text);

    HtmlNode price = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='bold colorwhite size11 floatLeft textCenter cartbox_right']");

    if (price != null) {
        return price.InnerHtml;
    }

    else
        return "nothing found";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need `InnerText` and `Split` to get `150,42` (if that's what you want):

```
HtmlNode priceNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='bold colorwhite size11 floatLeft textCenter cartbox_right']");
string price = priceNode.InnerText.Split(';').Last().Trim();
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Haven't been on C# for a while... Thanks! Just wondering - it says System.Array doesn't contain any definition for 'Last'. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Metro1337: That's part of the `System.Linq` namespace. Are you on <= .NET 2? If you can't use `LINQ` you have to use `Dim split = priceNode.InnerText.Split(';') Dim price = split(split.Length-1).trim`

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you! It almost works perfect, it just still displays 0,00. Hard to figure out why. Might have any ideas for that aswell?

Comment: @Metro1337: where and how do you output it? Have you used the debugger to see what happens?

Comment: Oh damn, I forgot everything about it really to much PHP. I'm using a button for the output lbl_price.Text = getTextfrom(); How can you exactly use the debugger?

Comment: @Metro1337: you just have to set a breakpoint, for example at the line `string price = ...`. Therefore you need to click on the left side beside the line-number. You can for example use the quick-watch window to inspect all values. However, are you sure that the span-`InnerText` is `&euro; 150,42`?

Comment: Ahh, I see! Well, as you can read on my question the output from the beginning has been euro; 0,00 but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Metro1337: i know, but if i use your string and output the price i get `150,42`. So there must either be a problem with your input or output.  But i have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: I'd like to check my input first. Can you tell me how to convert this into a string? var doc = webGet.Load(txtURL.Text);

Comment: `HtmlDocument.Load(string path)` loads the document from a file-path, so what do you want to convert to string and why? You should inspect `priceNode.InnerText` in the debugger. You could also read the file with `File.ReadAlltext` and pass this string to `LoadHtml`: `webGet.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText(path));`.

Comment: Since the comments here would extend the question too far I'm going to do another question but will keep this one here because it might help other users. Thanks for your help anyway